# std::vector append with std::move

Tags: c++, c++11, move, stdvector, move-semantics

Is it possible to append to an `std::vector` another `std::vector` by moving the second into the first?
If so, how?

I'm only aware of this syntax to perform the append operation:

```
vec_a.insert( vec_a.end(), vec_b.begin( ), vec_b.end( ) );
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Omit a copy of the appended elements? That's not possible as each vector uses its own internal, continuous storage on the heap.

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720122/is-there-a-standard-way-of-moving-a-range-into-a-vector

Comment: @ypnos sometimes objects are movable but not copiable